# Jest spyOn is reporting a method was called with a different object than what it was actually called with

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm using Jest `spyOn` to track a method on Vue router. The Vue method I'm testing looks like this:

```
myMethod() {
  this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
}
```

I want to ensure that `$router.push` was called, so in my test I have this:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.$router, 'push');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: "login" });
```

This test fails, though, with the error:

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
        {"name": "login"}
      as argument 1, but it was called with
        {"name": "login", "params": {}, "path": "/login"}.
```

No problem, I can update the test to the following and it works:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  name: "login",
  params: {},
  path: "/login"
});
```

My question is: why does the Jest spy report that it was called with an object with three properties, but when we look at the actual method call, it only has one property?

Comment: What does `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` give you?

Comment: @Krimson it passes!

Comment: So I'm assuming it was called more than once internally?

Comment: @Krimson the method I'm testing only calls router.push once, and AFAIK the method shouldn't have been called at all other than that.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I misunderstood your response

Answer (score 1):

`vue-router` add some default values to `params` and `path` properties. When you use `spyOn` you will detect the other parameters also which are assigned by `vue-router`. If you add explicit the `spy` to the `push` method then you will see only the `name` property.

Try this:

```
const spy = jest.fn();
wrapper.vm.$router.push = spy;
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: "login" });
```

Comment: The problem is that $router.push is a read-only property :/ That's why I used the spy rather than overwriting it with a mock function. The thing that interests me is that spyOn won't detect any values added by default. Is that right?